# MEAN stack uploading files to db on form when pressing submit

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, mean.io

I am trying to upload pdf files through a form to mongodb through mongoose. I want the file to be uploaded only once the form is submitted.

It seems like grid-fs and ng-file-upload are the best way to go, but I am having a hard time finding any good tutorials. Can anyone help me get this working?

I have seen similar questions but I am new to the MEAN stack and I am finding them hard to understand.

I am also going to want to be able to load the file and show it in the page, but that is a further question,